# ASP.NET MVC 1 & MVC 2 RC on Visual Studio 210 Beta 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm about to create a new virtual machine for development. I'm really interested in the new Visual Studio Beta 2 and the ASP.NET MVC 2 RC, but I'm also working on a ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project. Does VS2010 Beta 2 work with both MVC 1 and MVC 2 RC? Will I have problems or it's fine to to that?

I will run everything over a Win7 64bit installation.

I really appreciate that. Thanks guys.

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MVC 2 RC will not work with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. Actually, the runtime bits will, but the design time bits will not. The next beta of Visual Studio 2010 will include an updated MVC 2. For the time being, MVC 2 Beta 2 is the most recent MVC 2 which will work on VS 2010.

Comment: Hmmm I see... Well, I can still have both Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 Beta 2 working in the same machine right? Do you know when MS will release a new VS beta? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, 2008 and 2010 can coexist. No, but rumor says February.

Comment: Great. I think I'll start with this setup (VS08 + VS10) and later this year I delete the 08. Thanks Craig. ;)